# How do I keep dust away when applying a laptop screen protector?

Tags: dust

I'm getting a matte anti-glare screen protector for my 15 inch laptop tomorrow, and many of the reviews I have read say you practically need a cleanroom to keep dust particles off the back of the protector/front of the screen during the application process. I've also heard that the protector tends to get statically charged and literally attract particles to itself during this process.

Is there some way I could remove dust from a small room where I plan to apply this screen protector in? Could I try applying it somewhere like my garage, which I assume would have less dust floating around? Better yet, is there some way I can measure dust content in a room to help me select a suitable place to do this?

I've thought about doing this outside too. Would the humidity/outside conditions be worse for the application process than dusty inside conditions?

Comment: Easiest way to make sure it's put on right--take it somewhere and have the protector put on by a professional. They are very careful, but if anything does get under the protective screen while they are putting on the will usually redo it for no extra cost. Plus a lot of them have warranties/discounted replacements if the screen bubbles or breaks.

Answer (score 2):

- **Keeping the humidity between [40-50](http://www.surrey-cleaning-angels.co.uk/are-you-making-you-home-dustier/)**% will prevent some static, stopping some dust from collecting. (or if this is a short job, steam up the room and leave it for 20 or so minutes to let the dust settle, then do what you need to do)
- Use an [**ionizer**](http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=63647) to make the dust stop from getting to your screen.
- **Air purifiers and filters** on the vents.
- [and this is](http://www.kadansky.com/files/newsletters/2015/2015_05_28.html) a good method for cleaning your screen